# Conditionally sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this simple query

```
select * from users where name = 'User1'
```

I'd like to extend the query's functionality whatever the query returns 0 records the query will fetch the data by other clause.

```
where name = 'Default'
```

If the first clause will fetch some records the second clause will be ignored.

**EDIT**

Oracle

Comment: SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle?...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'User1'
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = 'Default' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE name='User1')
```

Comment: @Quassnoi: Wasn't yours slightly better in terms of performance, having one less `SELECT`? ... EDIT: But I guess that was assuming `name` was unique.

Comment: I don't know oracle - I posted this before the OP specified that. It's verbose, but works on SQL Server. How about Oracle?

Comment: @mdma: your query will work in `Oracle` too (and yield correct results).

Comment: @Quassnoi - Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 4):

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT * from users where name = 'User1')
   SELECT * from users where name = 'User1';
 ELSE
   SELECT * from users where name = 'Default';
```

Comment: The only answer so far that gives the correct results in all situations.

Comment: @Quassnoi, rdbms was not specified first time. :), @mdma provided correct answer for oracle.

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 * from users where name in ('User1', 'Default') order by name desc
```

:P

Comment: I think Oracle uses something different than `TOP`. This will work though if there is a unique constraint on `name`.

Comment: @Martin: I think the OP didn't specify Oracle originally.

Comment: @OP: if you do use this, be very careful understanding that this query depends on the alphabetic order of `User1` and `Default`.

Comment: The author's query can return more than 1 record while this one can return at most 1. In `SQL Server`, this could be worked around using `TOP 1 WITH TIES`, but this is `Oracle`.

Comment: @Quassnoi - You can use `RANK` to deal with ties.

Comment: And what does that return if the username queried for is "Anna" instead of "User1"... Then you get the wrong result, so I'm wondering why people are voting this answer up when it's clearly wrong.

Comment: and what if it's more than 2 names?

To be honest I posted this as a sort of joke, hence the :P. If the OP uses this type of query, as I said he must be careful to understand why it works and make sure that it doesn't dig him into a hole. I don't like just writing other peoples' code for them; i am just showing the strategy.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH T AS   (
        SELECT  users.*,
        RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'User1' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS RN
        FROM    users
        WHERE   name IN ( 'Default','User1')
        )
SELECT * FROM T
WHERE   RN = 1
```